# Figure Out The Language: Min

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, computer-puzzle

Imagine there is a programming language in which you can only evaluate expressions. Expressions have operators and constants.

There are three types of constants.
Numbers - Any number from 0 to infinity.
Text - Any text, must be enclosed in double quotes.
Booleans - true or false.

The operators that can be used are small, I'll list them here.

```
+  | Plus
++ | Concatenate
-  | Minus
-- | Unary
/  | Divide
// | Floor division
*  | Multiply
^  | Exponent
=  | Compare (= used here because the assignment operator is not =)
%  | Type compare
!  | Not
&  | And
|  | Or
<  | Less then
>  | Greater then
<= | Less then or equal to
>= | Greater then or equal to
:  | Assignment operator (separate the names with commas to unpack multiple values)
;  | Declaration operator
<> | Flip variable (if variable is True then change it to False and vica versa)
:+ | Increment operator
:- | Decrement operator
-> | Send to STDOUT
<- | Get from STDIN
#  | Loop operator (use i to get current iteration)
```

The Concatenate operator takes one text and joins another text onto it, so `"a" ++ "a"` would be `aa`. The Unary operator flips the sign of a number. So, `---3` will result in `3` and `--3` will result in `-3`. Type Compare checks if two values' types are the same and returns true if they are else false.

There are if and if-else statements.
cond_then_body_end_ - Executes the body if cond is true
cond_then_body1_else_body2_end_ - Executes body 1 if cond is true else body 2

Lines are underscore-terminated.

This is a minimal programming language. (Because I don't want to spend hours creating a proper one just for this puzzle)

There are no functions in this minimal programming language. Let's call it Min (short for Minimal).

To write a Hello, world program in Min you can write this code.

```
-> "Hello, world!"_
```

Output: Hello, world!

To print every number from 0 to 9 you can use this code. (it ends with a space, not a new line)

```
10 # -> i_
```

Output: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Even for a more complex program that receives two values from STDIN, adds them and writes them back to STDOUT, checks if the result is greater then 100 and based on that writes another value back to STDOUT. You only need to use this program.

```
x: <-_
y: <-_
-> x+y_
x+y > 1000_then_-> "That's huge!"_else_-> "That's small!"_end_
```

Output (if given 2 and 2 for x and y): 4 That's small!
Output (if given 502 and 503 for x and y): 1005 That's huge!

There is a catch though, negative numbers are turned into two numbers! The first one being the number subtracted from zero and the second one being zero.

```
x, y: -3_
-> x_
-> y_
```

Output: 3 0

If you try to assign it to one value, it of course results in an error.

```
x: -3_
```

Output: Error: Expected one value(s), got two value(s)

If you try to assign -0, it will be treated as a negative number.

```
x, y: -0_
-> x_
-> y_
```

Output: 0 0

Any value put after - in a variable declaration will be treated as a negative number! Let's call them negative lists now since they aren't limited to just numbers and are a list of two items.

```
x, y: -"a"_
-> x_
-> y_
```

Output: a 0

There's a second catch though! Any operations on negative lists will look at the first item in the list, double it then add 1! (For text that would be taking the text then copying it and joining it back with the original text and adding an empty text)

```
-3 + -2_
```

1. -3 evalutes to 3 0
2. -2 evalutes to 2 0
3. + operator looks at the first items of each list, so 3 and 2 in this case
4. Double each item, 3 to 6 and 2 to 4 so, 6 and 4
5. Add one to each item, 6 to 7 and 4 to 5, so 7 and 5
6. This means that -3 + -2 is actually 7 + 5

So the output is 12.

Now figure out the output of this Min code and explain why/how.

`x:<-_x%1_then_y:-x+--x-x_z:y<=x//2_z=true_then_z:-"a"++-"z"_->z_else_z:5_->z_end_end_`

(An actual programming language like Min would be a bad idea since code could quickly become unreadable like the above, in this case it's a challenge but in other cases it will just be harmful)

Comment: What does the operator `--` / `unary` do?

Comment: Hi OP, good job on being thorough with the explanation. To me, this seems a bit too.. specific(?) to be very interesting; the busywork required for struggling through all the arbitrary (occasionally even gratuitous) complications seems to outweigh any possible reward or revelation that may (or may not) be awaiting at the end of the solve.

Comment: @Bass That's true, I could have been a bit less specific but I don't want to make it broad. I was inspired by [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24014/figure-out-the-language) puzzle.

Comment: @Bass Also the feedback that I get from the answer is that I should have been more specific.

Comment: Regarding your examples for the Unary operator: You say that `---3` results in 3. Does this get parsed as `--(-3)` or `-(--3)`? If the former: What does Unary do when applied to a "negative list"? If the latter: You say that `-x` results in a "negative list", which is the two values `x 0`. What if `x` is a negative number, say, -3? Does this then result in the "negative list" `-3 0`? Or in just the single value `3`? Also, what does Concatenate do when applied to "negative lists"?

Comment: It gets parsed as `--(-3)`. Unary when applied to a negative list will parse the negative list so in case of 3 0, that would parse out to 7 and then do what it does. It will flip the sign, so 7 would go to -7. Same for concatenation.

Comment: Okay, in that case my only remaining question is what "Minus" is supposed to do when used a a binary operator. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: When used as a binary operator? Could you explain more?

Comment: Oh when used as a binary operator, it switches the sign to negative, if the sign is already negative then it won't do anything. So 3 to -3 and -3 to -3.

Comment: Wait you mean x minus y? Because in that case of course it just subtracts y from x.

Comment: Your guess about how Minus works as a binary operator is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether this solution is correct or not depends on what `-` / "Minus" is supposed to do when used as a binary operator instead of an unary one.

<s>Full solution depens on what `--` / "Unary" and `++`/ "Concatenation" are supposed to do, as well as what a comparison does outside of an assignment or an if statement.</s> These have now been answered.

Note that the notation of Min is very confusing and completely different from "normal" mathematical notation. If something in this answer is typeset in monospace like `-x+5` or in quotes like "Minus x Plus 5", it's Min, and if it is typeset using LaTeX like $-x+5$, it's "normal" mathematical notation.

First, let's

> make the program a bit more readable by replacing `_` with newlines and introducing indentation:
>
> ```
> x:<-
> x%1
> then
>   y:-x+--x-x
>   z:y<=x//2
>   z=true
>   then
>     z:-"a"++-"z"
>     ->z
>   else
>     z:5
>     ->z
>   end
> end
> ```

The first thing happening is

> `x:<-`, which reads something from STDIN and stores the result in `x`.

Now, we can see that

> if `x%1` is not true, nothing gets printed - that's the lines `x%1`, `then`, and the final `end`.

<s>I guess that</s> this means that

> the types of `x` and `1` are compared, and if they are different i.e. if something other than a number is inputted, the `then...end` block is skipped. <s>However, I'm not sure because `%` isn't really described - it's just documented as `Type compare`.</s>

Udate: This guess was right, and this operation has now been described in more detail in the question.

Next comes

> `y:-x+--x-x` which adds the "negative list" `x 0` to "unary `x`", subtracts `x` from that, and assigns the result to `y`. <s>I have no idea what this is supposed to do, because what "unary" does is not described at all.</s>
>
>  Udate: This has now been described: `--x` equals $-x$, and `-x` effectively equals $2x+1$. (Don't let the notation confuse you!) So, the part `-x+--x` is effectively $(-x) + (2x+1) = x+1$. Then, we calculate "`-x+--x` Minus x" - and I'm stuck again, because "Minus" as a binary operator is not described.

I guess that

> "Minus" as a binary operator just subtracts its second argument from its first argument, like in usual programming languages. Then, `-x+--x-x` equals $(x+1) - x = 1$, and the line `y:-x+--x-x` is just a convoluted way to set `y` to 1.

Then comes

> `z:y<=x//2`. This sets `z` to `true` if y is less than or equal to `x` divided by 2, rounded down (and `false` otherwise). If my previous guess is correct, this checks if $x >= 2$ (and stores the result in `z`).

> `z=true`, `then`, `else`, and the first of the two `end`s comprise another if-else statement.

<s>Now, I'm almost completely stuck, because</s>

> <s>both the `then` and `else` block start with a comparison: the `then` part starts with `z=-"a"++-"z"`, which compares `z` with something complicated; and the `else` part starts with `z=5`, which compares `z` with 5.</s>

<s>Maybe</s>

> this is a mistake, and should read `z:-"a"++-"z"` and `z:5`, respectively?
>  That would make sense because in both cases, `z` is printed afterwards, and that print is the last operation of the program in both cases.

Udate: Turns out this guess was also correct!

<s>In this case,</s> the `else` block

> just prints 5: first, it assigns 5 to `z` (`z:5`); then, it prints `z` (`->z`).

The `then` block

> is `z:-"a"++-"z"`, followed by `->z`. The first statement "concatenate"s the "negative lists" `"a" 0` and `"z" 0`, and then stores the result to `z`. <s>Again, no idea what this should do, because `++` / `concatenate` is not described either, like `unary`.</s>
>
>  Update: This has been described now. Concatenate first "parses" the "negative lists" which are its arguments. "Parsing" a "negative list" is described as follows: `look at the first item in the list, double it then add 1! (For text that would be taking the text then copying it and joining it back with the original text and adding an empty text)`.
>
>  If I interpret the second part about texts correctly, I think that `-"a"` concatenates two copies of "a" and the "empty text", which I guess equals "aa". Similarily, `-"z"` equals "zz". Then, those two strings are concatenated, resulting in "aazz". This string is then stored to `z` - that's the first statement `z:-"a"++-"z"`. The second statement just prints `z`, which will equal "aabb" at this point.

### Summarized description

> This program reads an integer from STDIN - if something other than an integer is inputted, it exits immediately.
>  If that integer is less than 2, the program prints 5, and if it is greater than or equal to 2, the program prints aabb.

Comment: Okay, I'll need to make this more detailed.

Comment: I also made a mistake, I am so used to using `=` for declarations that I used `=` instead of `:`, I am going to fix that.

Comment: This is correct but I will take one more read through this before accepting it as the right answer.